# password type input but show some of the text for different user roles

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, express

I am creating a user management system which have 2 user roles:
**Admin** and **Staff**

When admin checking the user information it will show all the data that query from database

Example:
[image]

my aim is to hide the phone number/ contact number when it show to the **Staff** user
and only show them the last 4 digits of the phone number

example :

[image]

I have no idea how to make this archieve

Comment: You *probably* want this at a deeper level than the UI input otherwise it would be easy to bypass.  Does your DB query know who the user is or can it pass in a parameter?  If not at the DB level then in your code-behind, something like:  `user.Phone = "****"" + user.Phone.Substring(4)` - syntax depends entirely on your back-end code, but you get the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of masking the input in the UI, it's better to change the actual value in the backend with a some code like this:

```js
phoneNum = '####' + phoneNum.substring(4)
```

this is also better that just change the input type because it would also be easely bypassed.

Comment: Thanks for freedomn-m and AnonHexo very much and I use
<%=customers_profile[i].phone_no.substring(customers_profile[i].phone_no.length - 4) %>
to get the result what I want.